# eslint-config-react-app throws Definition for rule 'getter-return' was not found

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I've just applied https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app to my project.

For almost each file I get this error

> 1:1  warning  Definition for rule 'getter-return' was not found  getter-return

Based on docs, I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I can disable this rule and get rid of warnings, but I would like to know what is wrong with the code.

Sample file that has this error:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SomeProvider } from 'common/components';
import ButtonHOC from './ButtonHOC';

const Button = props => {
  return (
    <SomeProvider>
      <ButtonHOC {...props} />
    </SomeProvider>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: without your code it's hard to say, but that linter warning can trigger if you have any function with "get" in it that doesn't return something

Comment: First lines differ, usually this is some kind of import, named or default. The thing is that this warning is for almost all files.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

Try updating `eslint` - most likely you have a rule definition that's only included in a newer version of eslint.